# Within a view function is there a way to return a string along with a response object?

Tags: python, flask

The following snippet send a file to the browser.

```
# Prepare selected file for download...
filename = request.form.get('filename')
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

return send_from_directory( filepath, filename )
```

What if i want to print some lines before sending the file, as in:

```
# Prepare selected file for download...
pdata = pdata + '''Your file will be ready for download'''
padata = pdata + '''it will just atake a moment'''

filename = request.form.get('filename')
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

return send_from_directory( filepath, filename )
```

if i try to add pdata + reponse like:

```
return pdata + send_from_directory( filepath, filename )
```

i get an error that return should return a string only not string + response

Comment: this is in a function correct

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a string and a response object both, try this:

```
return (pdata, send_from_directory(filepath, filename))
```

This will return a tuple with both datatypes within.  You can't use a `+` symbol unless you've got 2 objects that are compatible, as an example, `"string" + "string"` or `(tuple,) + (tuple,)`

Comment: The outer `()` are redundant and not needed.  It would also be good to indicate how to retrieve the elements at the caller.

Comment: Although this solution seems very straightforward i get this `TypeError: Invalid status argument`

Comment: Also if i try `return send_from_directory(filepath, filename), pdata` i get `ValueError: unicode object contains non latin-1 characters`

Comment: @StephenRauch Well, I think i knew that, but I like explicitly wrapping them in parentheses just so I can see at a glance.  To be honest, I've never tried it without.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος Errors you are getting don't have anything to do with the `return` statement.  You're getting the error probably in the `send_from_directory()` function and the data isn't what is expected.

Comment: Yes, its that function that gives trouble because it cannot handle a filename having chars other that latin-iso. Cn you help me fix this?

Comment: I'll assume `filename` is the improper string.  try this if python2:  `send_from_directory(filepath, str(filename, 'utf-8'))`  You're probably not using python3 because string are already unicode by default, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just print before you return?

```
def add(a, b):
    print(f"{a} is being added...")
    print(f"{b} is being added..")
    return a + b

c = add(1, 2)
print(c)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 strings.py
> 1 is being added...
> 2 is being added..
> 3
> ```

Suggest:

```
print(f'{pdata} "Your file will be ready for download..."')
print(f'{pdata} "it will just atake a moment..."')

filename = request.form.get('filename')
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

return send_from_directory( filepath, filename )
```

Older Python:

```
print(f'{} "Your file will be ready for download..."'.format(pdata))
print(f'{} "it will just atake a moment..."'.format(pdata))

filename = request.form.get('filename')
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

return send_from_directory( filepath, filename )
```

Comment: Why only Python 3.6+?

Comment: So Vash, in my code, how do you propose i write it?

Comment: @StephenRauch for future reference, if I'm helping what if this format viable for older versions, as in `"{}",format(x)`, I just started programming this month so I only know of 3.6+, sorry

Comment: Yes, go with `.format()` for best breadth.  Python 2.7 is almost gone, but it will be with us a bit longer.  More importantly many learners seem to still be using 2.7.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος updated answer

Comment: So, i can actually use print within a view function and then also use return? I though only in return i was supposed to reurn the whole html data back to the browser.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος I would check the link posted for more information

Comment: i did but this approach gives me this error `TypeError: Invalid status argument` Perhaps this is because the 2nd tuple elemnt is send_from_directory